# How to install entire git repo with bower

Tags: git, bower

I want to install the jquery plugin [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) using bower. I've been running the following command:

```
bower install chosen --save
```

When it installs it though it gets all the compiled files only and doesn't get the original sass files. Is there a way to get bower to download the entire repository so that I get the source files as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chosen` package registerd with `https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen-package`

According to [Bower doc](https://bower.io/#install-packages), you can install chosen source with its git endpoint :

**steps:**

```
bower uninstall --save chosen 
bower install --save https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen.git
```

Then you will see the whole thing in `bower_component/chosen`.